# How can I insert characters as 'ë' without using ALT

Tags: windows, windows-xp

To insert the character "ë", I normally do <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> and then <kbd>e</kbd>. However here at work whenever I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> it's inserted instantly, without me able to press the <kbd>e</kbd> or any other character. To insert this at work, I do <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>. But I want the method I have at home, since this is a lot easier.

I believe this has todo with regional / language settings but I cannot find it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check what keyboard layout is installed at home through the **Region and Language** dialog:

[image]

Check what language you're using at home, then install that language on your work computer and select it as the default:

[image]

Comment: It's a bit different on XP, but could find it, yes. It needed a PC restart though to make it work.